# Implementing MySQL, PHP, and Angular on a server

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angular, server

Overview:
I want to setup a basic CRUD application on a server via PHP, Angular, and a MySQL PhpMyAdmin database. I've forked (https://github.com/vpnsingh/Angular-PHP) as a base template.

While deploying I've been uploading the DIST folder for UI, and adding the php files to a directory named 'backend' at the root/public_html server level.

I have everything in the MySQL database setup, I'm just trying to get the API call to work, any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
// dbconnection.php
$conn = mysqli_connect(
    'localhost',
    'zrbania_root',
    'password',
    'zrbania_AngularTemplate'
);



// backend.component.ts
    getData(){
        this.http.get('http://localhost/backend/read.php').subscribe(
            data => {
                this.fetchdata = data;
                console.log('Data fetched is successful ', data);
            },
            error => {
                console.log('Error', error);
                this.errorMsg = error;
            }
        );
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved through proper authentication and server end points for the crud operations provided by the PHP files.